# Decaying value over time expontentially

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, datetime

I want to create a sorting algorithm that takes an items score (based on upvotes/downvotes) and sorts them based on an invisble underlying score that take time decay into account.

Being from the analytic philosophy side, my mathematical algorithms aren't always the best. What is a simple elegant way to solve for InverseTimeRelationship(currentItem.CreationDate) in the following example:

```
class Item()
{
  int upvotes;
  int downvotes;
  int SortScore;
  DateTime CreationDate;
}

var currentItem = GetSomeSpecificItemMethod();
int Score = currentItem.upvotes - currentItem.downvotes;
currentItem.SortScore = Score * InverseTimeRelationship(currentItem.CreationDate);
SortItemsBySortScore(Item[]);

InverseTimeRelationship(DateTime CreationDate)
{
  //Code To Write
}
```

The hope being that after a day, the SortScore would be a little lower, but after say 2-3 days no matter how many votes it has, it will disappear from the top of the list/front page.

Comment: Well, I'd start off with just `CONSTANT / (age of item)` as a baseline.  You can create things that decay quicker, more slowly, or with other more complex shapes, but a simple `1/age` gives you simple decay.  Also, this isn't really a programming question, so it's not on topic here.  If you had an algorithm and wanted to know how to implement it then it would be on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [the algorithm reddit uses](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588). It seems to be what you want.

Comment: I love Reddit, never knew this was out there. How much translation is needed to take this from Pyrex to C#?

Comment: @Wesley: If I were you, I'd just take the python implementation on the linked page and port it. It's very short and simple. :)

Comment: Will do. This just made my day. If you see that story on Reddit today, it was probably me.

Comment: Any resources on porting Pyrex(Python) to c#? Some of these terms aren't analogous to C# types.

Comment: @Wesley im sure it cant be that hard to figure out?  If you can't figure it out from the code, look at how the code relates to the actual equations.

Comment: @JonTaylor No, not that hard. I just want to make sure I do it right.

Comment: @Wesley Id suggest giving it a go :) always the best way, then if you think its not working or want to check if you have it right show us your code and we cant put your mind at ease or help you out further.  Deffinately the best way to learn though is to try :).

Comment: @Wesley: For converting DateTimes to timestamps, you can use [this implementation](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/07/10/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-.net-datetime.aspx). Apart from that, you should be fine. :)

Comment: You guys rock. Thanks for the above and beyond help.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

> e^-x (= 1/e^x)

See [this image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Plot-exponential-decay.svg) (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay)).

And here's code:

```
double InverseTimeRelationship(DateTime CreationDate)
{
    double HowFast = 0.1;
    return Math.Exp(-DateTime.Now.Subtract(CreationDate).Days * HowFast);
}
```

And you can try it with:

```
Text = InverseTimeRelationship(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3)).ToString();
```

Comment: Going to try out Both solutions. Right now, the Reddit code looks more thorough, but this would be easier to implement and is admittedly closer to my original question.